# Iterate over DOM elements and dynamically add data-attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following DOM structure and I need to get the text inside my h1 or h2 tag (but always first-child) and add that text value as as data-attribute to the second-child.

```
<div class="my-item">
    <div class="mac">
        <h1>test123</h1>
        <div>p1</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="my-item">
    <div class="mac">
        <h2>test456</h2>
        <div>p2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So my DOM after JS should look like this:

```
<div class="my-item">
<div class="mac">
    <h1>test123</h1>
    <div data-head="test123">p1</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="my-item">
<div class="mac">
    <h2>test456</h2>
    <div data-head="test456">p2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I attempted to do this by getting the list of all selectors and iterating over the list, but it wouldn't add the data-attributes and I don't see any console error. I believe the way I'm doing it is unable to find the elements:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div.my-item"); 
for (var i=0, max=items.length; i < max; i++) { 
  var itemH = $( "div.body:first-child" ).find(items[i]); 
  var itemP = $( "div.body:nth-child(2)" ).find(items[i]); 
  itemP.setAttribute('data-head', itemH.text()); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-item">
 <div class="mac">
  <h1>test123</h1>
  <div>p1</div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="my-item">
 <div class="mac">
  <h2>test456</h2>
  <div>p2</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect that you'll do your research and make an attempt at a solution before posting here. When you do post, we expect that you'll provide what you've tried along with a ***specific*** question about what's not working. This is not a place to post requests for solutions that you haven't made an attempt on.

Comment: this is a very basic question, just try to find the solution here or in the jquery documentation

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried to iterate and get the elements but it didn't quite work: 
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div.my-item");
  for (var i=0, max=items.length; i < max; i++) {
 var itemH = $( "div.body:first-child" ).find(items[i]);
        var itemP = $( "div.body:second-child" ).find(items[i]);
        itemP.setAttribute('data-head', itemH.text());
}

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you tried there, rather than in the comments. Also, please be very clear *"it didn't quite work"* doesn't tell us much. Did you get an error? What did happen?

Comment: You're mixing native DOM apis with jQuery objects.  And you aren't iterating over the array of elements selected.  setAttribute will fail

Answer (score 2):

When you use JQuery selectors, they return a JQuery wrapped set object, which is not a native object in JavaScript, so when you try to call `setAttribute()` on that JQuery object, you will get an error message in your developer's console.

Really, JQuery is overkill for this problem. If you just locate each second child of the respective groups and loop over them, you can update its `data-head` attribute to include that `div`s previous sibling element's text using the [`dataset` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset).

```js
// Get all the second child elements within the my-item groups
var items = document.querySelectorAll("div.my-item > div.mac > :nth-child(2)"); 

// Loop over the returned node list with the Array.forEach() API
// which is simpler than for loops because there's no index you
// have to manage.
items.forEach(function(item){
  // Set data-* attribute using the dataSet API
  item.dataset.head = item.previousElementSibling.textContent;
  console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="mac">
    <h1>test123</h1>
    <div>p1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="mac">
    <h2>test456</h2>
    <div>p2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly target the `<h1>` and and `<h2>` elements inside the div with class `.my-class` like this:

```js
$(".my-item h1, .my-item h2").each(function() {
  $(this).next("div").attr("data-head", $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="mac">
    <h1>test123</h1>
    <div>p1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="mac">
    <h2>test456</h2>
    <div>p2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update: As mentioned in the comments, the header tags could not only be h1 and h2, but everything up to h6. To target all header tags, it's possible to use [`:header`](https://api.jquery.com/header-selector/):

```js
$(".my-item :header").each(function() {
  $(this).next("div").attr("data-head", $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="mac">
    <h1>test123</h1>
    <div>p1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="my-item">
  <div class="mac">
    <h2>test456</h2>
    <div>p2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It sure give me pointers but in my case the h tags can be anything from h1..h6. 
Any other way around it instead of iterating over h1 and h2?

Comment: @user2526590 I've just adjusted my answer with an update to target all header elements.